# Getting the data URI of an image from HTML tag without XHR

Tags: javascript, image, data-uri

I have seen many Q/A on StackOverflow on how to get the data URI from an image tag (as "Copy the image as Data URI" in the contextual panel in Chrome) but every single answer contains XHR or using a canvas (assuming you have the control on the image from the beginning).

I want to get the data URI from the image without reloading again the URL (to avoid CORS error).

Ultimately, my goal is to format the image to an array of RGB pixels, so I can use it like that. Then I would be able to apply some transformations or processes like "if the image is more than 90% red, don't show it" by using a "homemade" browser extension.

If you have any idea on how I could get this, I'll be really grateful.

Comment: Can’t do that for exactly the reason using a canvas requires CORS.

Comment: Yep I know, that's why I'm asking if there is a way to "intercept" the loading of image tags at first, even before the image showing on the browser

Comment: To be a little more specific, you can’t do that for exactly the same *security* reason using a canvas requires CORS. Wouldn’t be much security if there were a way around it. So, no.

Comment: Er, wait, this is a browser extension? You don’t need to worry about CORS, then… (but it’ll be more efficient to intercept the request anyway, so look at the webRequest API – the request type will indicate whether it’s for an image).

Comment: Oh ok, thanks for the clarification, though I don't really know in what way is that a __security__ to prevent user to transform an image already loaded and showing on the user screen, you can do that for text, I don't really see the difference

Comment: Yep it's for a homemade browser extension, I've some personnal issues and want to prevent my browser from showing certain images. I know already how to detect if I don't want to see the image, now I need to get the array of rgb pixels in my pages

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176827/discussion-between-suicideboy-and-ry).